# How to Fix “Are You Sure You Want to Do This”, while uploading my theme?

Tags: errors, server, 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

While uploading my theme is live server it shows this message "Are You Sure You Want to Do This".

My theme contain visual composer and revolution slider,But interesting thing is when I upload the theme without slider revolution, it uploads normally.

So I think it may cause about the theme folder size.without slider revolution it is 8M and with it, the theme size is 15M. But my php ini file is with this status: memory_limit = 128M ,upload_max_filesize = 60M, post_max_size = 60M.

So, I am confused about the problem.I am working on a custom theme and I am using Digital Ocean as server provider.

Thanks

Comment: Try the solution given in this blog http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-are-you-sure-you-want-to-do-this-error-in-wordpress/

you can generate key from here: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Though I have increased the upload limit, but the error was showing.I managed the upload using filezilla.